# Send variable value or string from Android App to Arduino via HC-05 Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth

I am creating an Android App with Android Studio. When I press a button, I want to send a variable value to Arduino, via Bluetooth HC-05, maybe print it in the Serial Monitor. This is the code that I am using, but it doesn't work as intented.

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();   
BluetoothDevice hc05 = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:91:FD:3E:F0");


BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;

    try {
        btSocket = hc05.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);            
        btSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

BluetoothSocket finalBtSocket = btSocket;

button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = finalBtSocket.getOutputStream();
            finalBtSocket.getOutputStream().write("S".toString().getBytes());
           //outputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(puk));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
});
```

I have the "puk" variable that I am inserting in another Activity, and passing it through to this Activity. What I want is to be able to print the value of that variable in the Serial Monitor.

If you have any information that can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;

        try {
            btSocket = hc05.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
            
            btSocket.connect();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Status_Poarta.this);

            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setMessage("Connection is successful");

            builder.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();





        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Status_Poarta.this);

            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setMessage("No connection established");

            builder.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();


        }

    BluetoothSocket finalBtSocket = btSocket;

    
    button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = finalBtSocket.getOutputStream();                 
                outputStream.write(puk.getBytes());   
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Mersi Emi, ai si terminat proiectul la IP ?

Comment: Aproape, mai avem de facut cateva conexiuni.